# How many ways to get 21 given a list of numbers? How to get all posible combinations of numbers?

Tags: c++, arrays, numbers, combinations

All right, so I have to solve this problem in which the user gives a list of 7 or `k` numbers and I have to tell how many ways are there to get `21` or `n` using sums and substractions of these numbers. **I have to use all numbers.**
For example, user gives the number: (1 3 4 5 9 1 7). I can put all these numbers into an array of length 7 and count how many times do I get 21 usings sums and/or subs of these numbers: 
`1 +/- 3 +/- 4 +/- 5 +/- 9 +/- 1 +/- 7`.

The code for this problem is already made:

```
count-twenty-one(int* dig, int n, int pos, int sum, int res) {
   if (pos==n) {
       if(sum==21)
         return res++;
   }
   count-twenty-one(dig, n, pos+1, sum+dig[pos], res)
   count-twenty-one(dig, n, pos+1, sum-dig[pos], res)
}
```

As you can see this makes a DFS (Deep First Search) to find how many ways are there to get 21. Now, the actual problem is how to know how many ways are there to get 21 **using** combinations of given numbers, and again I have to use all of them. For example, user gives the number:

`(0 0 0 0 2 1 0)`. There's no way I can get 21 using 0 + 0 - 0 + 0 + 2 + 1 + 0. But If I append the 2 and the 1 and sum/sub it with the other 0 I can get 21. 
`0 + 0 + 0 - 0 + 21 -0 = 21` Let'say the user now gives (2 3 9 8 5 0 7). With this I could for numbers like `23 98 5 7` and try to see how many ways are there to get the desired number.  But then again I can have `239 8 507`.

So I guess the main problem is to get all posible combinations of numbers from (1 to k) -*K is the length of numbers list*- and then use `count-twenty-one` in all of them. How do I do this? I'm using C++ and arrays.

**edit**:

This problem can be solved by gettin all possible paritions of the given array, then putting al those partitions through `count-twenty-one`. Any ideas?

**edit 2**:
The numbers are 'ordered' this means with `(2 3 9 8 5 0 7)` I can't form combinations like `705 8 93 2`

Comment: Your question mixes two different problems. The first problem is to think of a suitable algorithm better than the brute-force approach (i.e. just trying all combinations). This has absolutely nothing to do with C++. The second problem is then to express this algorithm in C++. For the second problem, here's the most important thing to get right: do *not* use arrays. Use `std::vector`.

Comment: I still don't get why not using arrays, they're not so bad. Anyway, the whole problem sums up to getting all partitions of a given set, then use these partitions to see whether I can get the desired number (using + and - operations) with a given partition. :)

Comment: Arrays are so bad. Please have a look at the C++ FAQ: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/arrays-are-evil.html

Comment: Ok, got to use vectors now. :) It really makes things easier and I appreciate your help. But any ideas on how to solve the problem?

Comment: You are welcome. No ideas on the algorithm part of your problem, really, or rather I haven't even thought much about it. My core competence is C++, so I thought I'd leave the algorithm stuff to more specialised people :)

Answer (score 0):

For the brute force approach, following may help: https://ideone.com/jAVRDk

```
void print(const std::vector<int>& digits,
           const std::vector<int>& seps,
           const std::vector<std::string>& s) {
    std::cout << digits[0];
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != seps.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << s[seps[i]] << digits[i + 1] ;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

bool next(std::vector<int>& seps)
{
    for (auto it = seps.rbegin(); it != seps.rend(); ++it) {
        if (++*it == 3) {
            *it = 0;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void foo(std::vector<int> digits)
{
    const std::vector<std::string> s = {"", " + ", " - "};
    std::sort(digits.begin(), digits.end());

    do {
        std::vector<int> seps(digits.size() - 1, 0);

        do {
            print(digits, seps, s);
        } while (next(seps));
    } while (std::next_permutation(digits.begin(), digits.end()));

}
```

Comment: This works and it doesn't work at the same time. First it requires C++11 and I'd have to get Eclipse working and all that new school stuff. However, it takes every number and forms many combinations, `0 1 2` forms `2 1 0` for example, which is not valid for what I need (I know, my bad!)

Comment: With `foo({3,1,2,3})` I get `1233` as first line and then it starts printing it like it should, but still I think it should be `3 1 2 3`. This only creates the illusion(prints) of having the partitions. I actually need the partitions. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @DavidMerinos: Why would you need to "get Eclipse working", and what exactly is "all that new school stuff"? You can perfectly use GCC and MSVC without Eclipse, both can be downloaded for free (MS offers the "Express Edition" of Visual Studio which contains the full compiler), and both can be used on the command line without any IDE at all.

Comment: @DavidMerinos: Also, the C++11 features I can spot in this code are easily replaced: the initialization of `s` in `foo` with four `push_back()`s, the `auto` with `std::vector<int>::iterator`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl let's not lose the thread. I already got Eclipse working with C++11. I'm using vectors and I can use auto and all that. I really appreciate your help. The problem sums up to getting all possible partitions of the vector. I do not know how to do that.

Comment: @DavidMerinos: C++11 is just used for convenience, to avoid to type `std::vector<int>::reverse_iterator`. For your edit2, just remove the `sort` and the outer loop (with `next_permutation`) in `foo`.

Comment: @Jarod42 yeah ok, this prints the operations but what I need is the operands in a vector, if I call foo({3,1,2}) I'd like to get {3,1,2},{31,2},{3,12}. That's what I'd like. Any ideas? (I don't need printf's, I need vectors who contain that data)